# Autocomplete text box with values from mysql Wordpress database

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, wordpress

I have code that successfully works on my XAMPP server using my localhost database.

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() {
    var availableTags = [

        <?php

        $Database = "~";
        $DatabaseUserName = "~";
        $DatabasePass = "~";

        $connect = mysql_connect("~", $DatabaseUserName, $DatabasePass);
        @mysql_select_db($Database) or ("Database not found");

        $query = "SELECT ~ FROM ~";
        $result = mysql_query($query) or die ( $result."<br/><br/>".mysql_error());

        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo "\"". $row['~']."\", ";
        }

        // $result = mysql_query($query) or die ( $result."<br/><br/>".mysql_error());

        mysql_close($connect);

        ?>
    ];

    $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
        source: availableTags
    });
});
</script>
```

Then, the form input text field (in a table) has an id of "tags":

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <label for="~"><b>~</b><font color="red">*</font>:</label>
    </td>
    <td>
            <input id="tags" name="~" style="width: 250px;" onblur="~">
            <p id="~"></p>
    </td>

</tr>
```

What I'm trying to do is the exact same thing (autocompleting text box based on values in a MySQL database [in this case, Wordpress]) for my Wordpress site.

Comment: and what's the problem?

Comment: not autopopulating in text box ...

Comment: Please show the code you've done for Wordpress and we will help you from there

Comment: this is the code I'm trying to use (within the text editor tab of a single page in my Wordpress theme) (there's more html but I only included the code most relevant to my question here) ... I've read about registering a script for jQuery, which I've tried as well ... this code works with a local MySQL database I have on my localhost xampp server on a test site ...

Comment: and what problems are you having?

Comment: the autocomplete doesn't autocomplete with values from the connected MySQL table and column when the user begins to type in a value in the text field of the form input box ...

Comment: but it shows the dropdown list? what console says? It's impossible to answer if you don't provide any information.

Comment: it doesn't show anything, it's as if it's not functioning at all ... it should autocomplete / suggest options based on what the user begins to type in ... example, in my table I might have the value "green", when the user types the letter "g" in the text box, the autocomplete function should return a dropdown suggestion / option of "green" because it's in that linked table behind the jQuery function, hopefully this makes more sense?